# How to replace a .jar in JDeveloper?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

How can I replace a .jar with a newer version in JDeveloper?

I have tried the Replace With ->File on Disk option from menu but it is greyed out.  I also attempted to replace the .jar externally, but JDeveloper does not pick up the file has been modified like it does when I edit a file externally.

Answer (score 0):

In your project properties (Right click the project > Project Properties), go to the "Libraries and Classpath" menu item.

From there, you can remove and re-add the .jar file you want to update.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry I worded the question quite poorly. The .jar wasn't a project library but effectively just another file inside a package. Anyway it turns out JDeveloper was detecting the externally change, it just wasn't visually representing this (despite numerous refreshes...)

Comment: @LDM91 Closing/opening JDeveloper again should 'fix' that problem